# Will Ubuntu become rolling distro?

Tags: release-management

About a year ago I've read that Ubuntu is considering to become a rolling distro. Since then I couldn't found any fresher news about the topic.

Anyone has official information about the transition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those rumors where unfounded, Ubuntu's plans to become a rolling distro never saw the light of day even if they were ever discussed internally.

That news that you saw back in 2010 triggered a [response](http://theravingrick.blogspot.com/2010/11/ubuntu-is-not-moving-to-rolling-release.html) from Engineering Director of Ubuntu Rick Spencer.

On his blog post he clearly says

> *"Ubuntu is not changing to a rolling release"*.

He goes further down saying

> *"What the article was probably referring to was the possibility of making it easier for developers to use cutting edge versions of certain software packages on Ubuntu.This is a wide-ranging project that we will continue to pursue through our normal planning processes."*

What he refers here is the [+1 maintenance team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PlusOneMaintenanceTeamhttps://wiki.ubuntu.com/PlusOneMaintenanceTeam) which exist to ease the pressure on developers and make further releases easier and less stressful for them. It is not to be confused with a rolling release.

After that there was not further information or news about Ubuntu becoming a rolling release.
I am assuming that this can be answered better by someone from Canonical / Ubuntu. But since those rumors where proven false and there is no further information about this I can assume that a rolling release is not on the planning table.

Comment: There has been a push to make development versions more stable and usable (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PlusOneMaintenanceTeam). If this new team delivers all it's promises (it's hard), Ubuntu+1 will be something *close* to a rolling release.

Comment: That is not even close to a rolling release and was never the purpose:
> The +1 Maintenance Team is an experiment for the Ubuntu 12.04 development cycle to ensure that the development release stays in an installable state and that the archive is usable throughout the cycle.

Comment: I know this is not the purpose, the announced purpose is to bring more testers earlier to Ubuntu+1. Anyway, it will have all the packages continuously updated (even to betas) with a commitment to keep it working (likely no updates when close to the release). This is *close* (not the same) to a rolling release for me. Note that I', not saying that Precise (current Ubuntu+1) will be close to a rolling release, but that using the Ubuntu+1 (the next release) will.

Comment: Yeah, totally agree on what yoy say, i think this was what originated the rumors of ubuntu rolling in the first place. im on the mobile at the moment add any info that you might think needed to the answer, ill make it c wiki.

Comment: I prefer this to stay in the comments, it's not an answer to the question (the answer is NO) but a comment ;).

Comment: Ok, I added this myself, if you find anything else that might be nice to add to the answer dont be afraid and go ahead and edit it ;) Thx for the comments!