# Rolling Release in Ubuntu

Tags: release-management

Has Canonical decided to use a rolling release style in Ubuntu 14.04?

Will the normal 6 months release and 2 year updates continue?

Answer (score 0):

> Has Canonical decided to use a rolling release style in Ubuntu 14.04?

No.

> Will the normal 6 months release and 2 year updates continue?

The support period for LTS releases has changed. LTS releases 12.04 and later are now supported for five years on both the desktop and the server, although new releases are still scheduled biannually, and intermediate releases are still scheduled for six months between releases.

Sources:

[When will the next LTS version of Ubuntu be released?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51538/when-will-the-next-lts-version-of-ubuntu-be-released?rq=1)

http://www.zdnet.com/ubuntu-shuttleworth-and-rolling-releases-7000012503/

[Will Ubuntu become rolling distro?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87670/will-ubuntu-become-rolling-distro)

Comment: You have any sources?

Comment: You should be editing those into your post.. Always source your posts ;)